# Jquery Get ID on Each loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

html code

```
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($WltQRslt)){ 
            $Ldate = $row['LastDate'];
            $Bdate = $row['DateBought'];
            $id=sprintf('%s_%s',$Ldate,$Bdate);echo "<tr ><td class='center'><i class='fa fa-database fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['Server']}</td><td id ='".$row['SNo']."' ><i class='fa fa-line-chart fa-3x'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['Profit']}</td><td><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='date' date-start='$Bdate' date-end='$Ldate'></span></td>";
    }
?>
```

jquery code

```
$('table td[id]').each(function (index, element) {
    var id = $(element).attr('id');

     $.ajax({
        url:"get_server.php",
        method:"POST",
         data:{id:id},
         success:function(data) {
            var no=data.count;
            for(i=0; i<=no;i++) {
               var price  = data;
               console.log(price);
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

this jquery function get all the ID`s of each row contaning ID value. i want that on each iteration it get id from  proccess it then move on to another iteration?

Comment: Your HTML code looks a lot like PHP spaghetti

Comment: i am passing data to html table through php

Comment: "_i want that on each iteration it get id from proccess it then move on to another iteration_" Now that we know what you want can you maybe also tell us what you get? Does something not work? Do you get errors? Do you get the wrong ids?

Comment: `i want that on each iteration it get id from proccess it then move on to another iteration?` This is exactly what your loop is already doing: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/go14cyrw/

Comment: actualy when all the table is loaded then it calls this jquery function. i want to call it on every loop

Comment: If you mean you want to call it on every loop of the PHP code, then that's not possible as PHP runs on the server and JS on the client. If that's not what you meant then you'll need to give a much clearer description of your goal. Also note that it's really not a good idea sending AJAX requests in a loop as you'll flood your server. Aggregate all data in to a single request and send that, once.

Comment: exactly this is what i want on every loop call this functon. if its not possible. then is there any other alternative way. this jquery will actually process the id and make a value to display in same <td>

Comment: The alternative way is to do what you currently are.

Comment: but its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of each td element directly as element.id and change selector to 'table td'.

```
$('table td').each(function (index, element) {
    var id = element.id;

     $.ajax({
        url:"get_server.php",
        method:"POST",

...
```

And a sample snippet to see how it works..

```js
$('table td').each(function (index, element) {
  console.log(element.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td id='2' class='center'></td></tr>
    <tr><td id='1' class='center'></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to call this jquery in a loop. each time the data is populated through while loop.means at every iteration

Comment: If I am getting it right, the '.each' command itself is a loop like while and for. And in your code, for each td element, the ajax code will execute.

Comment: While loop is in php, server side which executes first. So the html table will be available for jQ when javascript executes after php has completed execution.

Comment: is there any other alternative to javascript which runs with php loop?

Comment: You can also do this inside the php while loop itself depending on how frontend is hosted, using curl (if hosted at a different server) and make a post request. So by the time execution reaches html/js, you will have both id and price. Check the SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code for curl post.